# Formatting JSON encoded data and php to replace an element

Tags: php, jquery

I wasn't sure of the best title to put for this, so apologies if it's not correctly describing my issue.

I'm working on a project in zen cart and I want to use jQuery to replace an existing image when my AJAX process has completed.
I'm sending data back on success using this line of code:

```
echo json_encode(array('name'=>zen_db_prepare_input($_POST['categories_name'][$language_id]),
                       'sort_order'=>zen_db_prepare_input($_POST['sort_order']), 
                       'categories_image'=>zen_db_prepare_input($categories_image->filename), 
                       'asHtml' => '<div class="alert alert-info update-notice update-'.$_POST['categories_id'].'"><strong>Category info updated</strong></div>'));
```

Zen Cart displays my original image using this code:

```
zen_image(DIR_WS_CATALOG_IMAGES . $categories->fields['categories_image'], $categories->fields['categories_name'], '100%', '')
```

so what I need is to replace $categories->fields['categories_image'] and $categories->fields['categories_name'] with the returned data from my json_encode array.

I've tried doing

```
elem.html(<?php echo zen_image(DIR_WS_CATALOG_IMAGES;?>obj.categories_image . obj.name<?php echo ", '100%', '')";?>).fadeIn('slow');
```

but that doesn't work and just causes an error 500. I think the elem.html line is incorrect as I don't know how to incorporate the two obj elements into the php code for generating the image output.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace elem.html line with this :

```js
elem.html("<?php echo zen_image(DIR_WS_CATALOG_IMAGES.$categories_image.$name,'100%','') ?>").fadeIn('slow');
```

for `$catrgories_image` and `$name` you can access them from your response data.
also echo will print a string type data so you need to wrap it inside ''.
i hope i was helpfull

Comment: It's giving me an error in console of "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" with the error being flagged on the line with the new code.  I can't see where the missing ) is though. Expanding the error in console shows elem.html("<img src="http://localhost/justsimplecart/images/categories/cat-head-1-min.jpg" border="0" alt="100%" title=" 100% ">").fadeIn('slow');

Comment: i think you need to change this : `"<?php echo zen_image(DIR_WS_CATALOG_IMAGES.$categories_image.$name,'100%','') ?>"` by this `'<?php echo zen_image(DIR_WS_CATALOG_IMAGES.$categories_image.$name,"100%","") ?>'` i think `src` attribute using `"` for image path. can you try it ?

Comment: That clears the error 500, but I have noticed one issue. Using '<?php echo zen_image(DIR_WS_CATALOG_IMAGES.$categories_image.$name,"100%","") ?>' doesn't quite follow the zen cart convention for zen_image layout, so the name isn't used, which then throws out the positioning of all the other data. Zen Cart is expecting to see IMG, NAME, ALT, PARAMS but  I've got $categories_image.$name, ALT, PARAMS, so $name is effectively ignored. I tried a comma instead of the period, but that just gave me a console full of errors.

Comment: from what i've found in [doc](https://www.zen-cart.com/docs/phpdoc-1-5-0/__filesource/fsource_functions__includesfunctionshtml_output.php.html#a160)  third and fourth paramers are for $width and $height and they should be int type  `zen_image(DIR_WS_CATALOG_IMAGES.$categories_image, $name, 100)`

Comment: Here's what I've found. Using elem.html("<?php echo zen_image(DIR_WS_CATALOG_IMAGES.$categories_image, $name, '100%'); ?>").fadeIn('slow'); the image is updated correctly, but it causes the content to be outside the tooltip. Using elem.html('<?php echo zen_image(DIR_WS_CATALOG_IMAGES.$categories_image, $name,"100%") ?>').fadeIn('slow'); the content is inside the tooltip, but the image doesn't update. Could it be that having it wrapped in ' ' rather than " " causes it to see $categories_image.$name as php variables, which would be empty as not set?